# Acoustic Handlings in a Small Room

Tags: acoustics, damping

Dear All,

I have a pretty urgent question here that I need to resolve in one of my record rooms:

I have a small room about 13 feet by 10 feet with a 10 foot ceiling.

The walls all have fabric on them that I can place something behind.

I've got about 2 inches to the dry wall from the fabric to the dry-wall that I can place something in.

This will mainly be used as a voice recording booth and I'd like to deaden it as much as possible.

I've been searching around and I found the "Echo Eliminator" cotton to be a good start to stuff behind the fabric.

Does anyone know of another type of deadening material that's about 2 inches thick? Preferably on the cheaper side but still effective?

What do you guys use in your studios?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of using stone wool, it is routinely used for just this purpose.  You can build up as many layers as you need.  It is normally used in loft insulation.

http://www.rockwool.co.uk/about+rockwool/what+is+stone+wool-c7-

Comment: Wow I have to try this stuff out. I can't really see anywhere that gives a good price - do you have a price off the top of your head to fit 150 square feet?

Comment: In the UK you can purchase it at virtually any DIY store.

Comment: Okay cool. I did some research and found out it's fiberglass. I guess that's not very safe?

Comment: Typically your wear a mask and gloves when you install it and you cover it with some additional material such as a hessian fibre.  It is perfectly safe and is a standard material for acoustic treatment in the UK, and is actually more popular and effective than acoustic foam.  

Comment: http://www1.rockwool.co.uk/sw66371.asp  for further info.